# Find number of breathe in and out in graph generated by breathe audio(wav) using jupyter/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, jupyter

Now I have plot of audio of breathing man
[(plot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5SCF.png)

Then I put it through FFT(Fourier Fast Transform)
[(plot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvg34.)

Now I have to find number of breathe in and out per minute

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import wavio
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftfreq
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import math
%matplotlib inline

rate, sampwidth, array = wavio.readwav('breath.wav')
data = array[:,0]
samples = data.shape[0]
plt.plot(data)
# here i have plot of audio

fft_out = fft(array)
fft_out = fft_out[:,0]
fftabs = np.abs(fft_out)
freqs = fftfreq(samples, 1 / rate)
plt.plot(freqs, fftabs)
# here i have fft plot
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: Please check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It basically argues why a minimal, complete, verifiable example is awesome. And i can say from experience that working out this part is sometimes enough to answer your question already because you might just discover the flaw in the process :>

Comment: Updated my post